# Entity Framework randomly inserting many duplicate records over a long period of time

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Rarely and apparently randomly, entity framework will insert many duplicate records. Can anyone explain why this behaviour occurs? This is the second project i've seen this in:

```
protected void btnAddQual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        QEntities ds = new QEntities();
        Qualification qual = new Qualification();
        qual.PersonID = ds.Persons.Where(x => x.Username == User.Identity.Name).Single().PersonID;
        qual.QualificationName = txtQualAddName.Text;
        qual.QualificationProvider = txtQualAddProvider.Text;
        qual.QualificationYear = txtQualAddYear.Text;            
        qual.Inactive = false;
        qual.LastUpdatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
        qual.LastUpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        ds.Qualifications.Add(qual);
        ds.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Qualifications Table:

```
public partial class Qualification
{
    public int QualificationID { get; set; }
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string QualificationName { get; set; }
    public string QualificationProvider { get; set; }
    public string QualificationYear { get; set; }
    public bool Inactive { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual Persons Persons { get; set; }
}
```

I've seen it create from three to 32 records in one button click, and when it does, the timestamps which can be spread across a good period of time (last time was 28 records, all identical apart from the primary key and timestamps, unevenly distributed over 23 minutes)

I've previously put this down to user or browser based behaviour, but last night it happened with me using the machine.
I didn't notice anything unusual at the time, but its infrequent occurance makes it a devil to track down. Can anyone suggest a cause?

Edit with additional information:

This is with .net framework 4.5.2 and EF 6.1.3

Edit to explain the bounty:

I've just seen this occur in the following code:

```
  using(exEntities ds = new exEntities())
        {
            int initialStations;
            int finalStations;
            int shouldbestations = numStations * numSessions * numRotations * numBlock;

            initialStations = ds.Stations.Count();


            for(int b = 1; b <= numBlock; b++)
            {
                for (int se = 1; se <= numSessions; se++)
                {
                    for (int r = 1; r <= numRotations; r++)
                    {
                        for (int st = 1; st <= numStations; st++)
                        {
                            Stations station = new Stations();
                            station.EID = eID;
                            station.Block = b;
                            station.Rotation = r;
                            station.Session = se;
                            station.StationNum = st;
                            station.LastUpdatedBy = User.Identity.Name + " (Generated)";
                            station.LastUpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                            station.Inactive = false;

                            ds.Stations.Add(station);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ds.SaveChanges();
```

In this instance, the number of iterations of each of the loops were: 
1, 2, 6, 5 respectively.

This one click (same timestamp) has duplicated the complete set of records

Comment: Well, in the `btnAddQual_Click()` handler you posted you always keep adding new `Qualification` entities to the context, I don't see any code searching for existing records to update. So everytime someone clicks on the associated button a new record will be created in the database. Also as a side note, assuming `QEntities` is you `DbContext` implementation: You should wrap always wrap the context in a `using` statement (i.e. `using (var ds = new QEntities()) { ... }`) to make sure it is properly disposed / closed.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear there's a completely seperate update button/process. This is generating multiple records off pressing this button once. Thanks for the tip on using, i'll fix that!

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the versions of Entity Framework and .NET Framework that are you using.

Comment: Nothing in the code you show can give rise to random behavior. It *must* be the environment the code runs in. There are known case where javascript keeps firing because of bugs in js libraries or duplicate libraries of different versions. The code blocks, when running in a plain console application, can't ever insert random numbers of duplicate records.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks, I suspected but i'm not sure what it could be: the page in this instance only have one piece of inconsequential javascript, fired on page load (it adds a css class to something else, in some circumstance) and i've had it happen on different machines, with different O/S on different browsers, but its too rare occuring for me to replicate and diagnose: any advice to pin it down would be appreciated

Comment: I've had to work on a WebForms site that suffered from what we called "double postback": almost any button press led to two ASP.NET Postback events being submitted. We never figured out the cause (years of development history before any of us were added to the team), and we had to resort to identifying/filtering duplicate events in the click handlers.

Comment: @PeterB was it every click, or just once every now and again?

Comment: Sorry I don't recall, this was 10 years ago...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where you need to add logging into your application. Based on your code, I do not believe Entity Framework is duplicating your data, rather that your code is being triggered in ways that you are not catering for.  Where I have seen EF duplicate records has been due to developers passing entities loaded from one DBContext and then associating them to entities created in a second DBContext without checking the DbContext and attaching them first. EF will treat them as "new", and re-insert them. From the code that you have provided, I do not believe this is the case, but it is something to watch out for.

Firstly, when dealing with web applications in particular, you should write any event handler or POST/PATCH API method to treat every call as untrustworthy. Under normal use these methods should do what you expect, but under abusive use or hacking attempts they can be called when they shouldn't, or carry payloads that they shouldn't. For example, you may expect that an event handler with a record ID of 1234 would only be fired when record 1234 is updated and the user pressed the "Save" button (once), however it is possible to:

- Receive the event more than once if the client code does not disable the button on click until the event succeeds.
- Receive the event without the client clicking the button when fired through a debugging tool.
- Receive the event with ID 1234 when a different record is saved, thanks to a user changing the Record ID in a debugging tool.

Trust nothing, verify and log everything, and if something is out of place, terminate the session. (Force log-out)

For logging, beyond the standard exception logging, I would recommend adding Information traces with an additional compiler constant for a production debug build to monitor one of these cases where this event is getting tripped more than once.  Personally I use `Diagnostics.Trace` and then hook a logging handler like Log4Net into it.

I would recommend adding something like the following:

```
#if DEBUG
  Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format("Add Stations called. (eIS: {0})", eID));
  Trace.TraceInformation(Environment.StackTrace);
#endif
```

Then when you do your count check and find a problem:

```
Trace.TraceWarning(string.Format("Add Station count discrepancy. Expected {0}, Found {1}", shouldBeStations, finalStations));
```

I put the compiler condition because Environment.StackTrace will incur a cost that you normally do not want in a production system. You can replace "DEBUG" with another custom compilation constant that you enable for a deployment to inspect this issue. Leave it running in the wild and monitor your trace output (database, file, etc.) until the problem manifests. When the warning appears you can go back through the Information traces to see when and where the code is being triggered. You can also put similar tracing in calls that loaded the screen where this event would be triggered to record IDs and User details to see if/how an event might have been triggered for the wrong eID via a code bug or some environmental condition or hack attempt.

Alternatively, for logging you can also consider adding a setting to your application configuration to turn on and off logging events based on logging levels or flags to start/stop capturing scenarios without re-deploying.

These kinds of issues are hard to diagnose and fix over something like StackOverflow, but hopefully logging will help highlight something you hadn't considered. Worst case, consider bringing in someone experienced with EF and your core tech stack short-term to have a look over the system as a second pair of eyes over the entire workings may also help point out potential causes.

One small tip. Rather than something like:

```
qual.PersonID = ds.Persons.Where(x => x.Username == User.Identity.Name).Single().PersonID;
```

use:

```
qual.PersonID = ds.Persons.Where(x => x.Username == User.Identity.Name).Select(x => x.PersonID).Single();
```

The first statement executes a "SELECT * FROM tblPersons WHERE..." where the entity isn't already cached and pulls back all columns, where only PersonID is needed. The second executes a "SELECT PersonID FROM tblPersons WHERE..."